# Find $r$ for a sum of increasing exponents

Tags: exponential-function

### Short Version: Find $r$

$$61.051 = \frac{(1-(1+r)^5)}{(1-(1+r))} * 10$$

(The answer is $0.1$. I am looking for the steps/process to find the answer)

### Detailed Version:

**Example Scenario: Purchasing Widgets**

The first widget costs $*x*. Each subsequent widget costs *r* times more than the last widget purchased (*x<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> * (1 + r)*).

**Illustration**

The following table illustrates the scenario for a base widget cost (*x<sub>1</sub>*) of $10 that increases 10% (*r*) with each additional unit purchased.

| N (units purchased) | x<sub>n</sub> (unit cost) | T (cumulative cost for N units) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 | 21 |
| 3 | 12.1 | 33.1 |
| 4 | 13.31 | 46.31 |
| 5 | 14.641 | 61.051 |

As shown, the first widget costs \$10, the second costs \$11 (\$10 * 1.1), and so on. Such that the total cumulative cost for five widgets is \$61.051.

The total cumulative cost for any *N* units may be found using:

$$T = \frac{(1-(1+r)^N)}{(1-(1+r))} * x_1$$

So for the example above:

$$61.051 = \frac{(1-(1+0.1)^5)}{(1-(1+0.1))} * 10$$

In other words, purchasing five widgets would cost $61.051.

**The Question**

If the first widget's cost x<sub>1</sub>, total cumulative cost *T* and number of widgets purchased *N* are known, how do we find the value of *r*.

** Work so far **

$$61.051 = \frac{(1-(1+r)^5)}{(1-(1+r))} * 10$$

$$\frac{61.051}{10} = \frac{\frac{(1-(1+r)^5)}{(1-(1+r))} * 10}{10}$$

$$6.1051 = \frac{(1-(1+r)^5)}{(1-(1+r))}$$

Here's where I start to derail...

$$log(6.1051) = \frac{1 - 5*log(1+r)}{1-(1+r)}$$

$$0.785693 = \frac{1 - \frac{5*log(1+r)}{5}}{1-\frac{(1+r)}{5}}$$

$$0.785693 = \frac{1-log((1+r)}{1-\frac{(1+r)}{5}}$$

...and now I am off the rails completely.

What are the steps to isolate $r$?

Thanks

Comment: I would start by $x=1-r$, and $1-x^5=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$. Then I think it is unlikely that you will find a simple closed formula for the solution. Although a closed formula exists for 4th degree equations.

Comment: Thank you ECL - If the problem were for 100 units, not 5, would the second parenthesis in your comment then become $(1 + x + x^2 + ... x^{100})$?  I will have to study this a bit more, I'm having difficulty visualizing finding $r$ from $x$ if $x$ includes $r$ in its definition. Looks like I have some reading in my future :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the formula you wrote
$$T = \frac{(1-(1+r)^n)}{(1-(1+r))} \, x_1$$ let  $A=\frac T{x_1}$,simplify the denominator to make
$$A=\frac{(1+r)^n-1} r$$ If $n>4$, no explicit solution ; then either numerical methods or *approximations*.

Since we know that $r \ll 1$, using
$$A=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k+1} \,r^k $$ truncate to some order and use series reversion. This would give
$$r=t-\frac{n-2}{3}  t^2+\frac{(n-2) (5 n-7)}{36}  t^3-\frac{(n-2) \left(17 n^2-44 n+29\right) }{270} t^4+O(t^5)$$ where $t=\frac{2 (A-n)}{(n-1) n}$.

Trying with your numbers $n=5$ and $A=6.1051$, this will give $r=0.0999342$ which does not seem too bad.

Adding two more terms in the expansion would give $r=0.0999969$

Comment: What I thought was a simple question has become a fascinating discussion.  Ultimately I was hoping for a closed formula (for use in programming) but I see now this is not possible. I tested your comment that n>4 cannot be solved using the microsoft math solver, sure enough, it stops trying at n=5. That's interesting. Your response gives me some terminology to dig deeper, thank you!

Comment: You say "Since we know that r≪1,..." I don't beleive we do know that.  We know that only for this simplified example, but it is possible widgets increase by more than 100% with each purchase.  Does that change the approach?